# Java spark concatenate object into one list using reduceByKey aviod nested list

Tags: java, arrays, apache-spark, object, reduce

I have a java spark rdd with (key,value) pair as (String, ArrayList). The ArrayList is an array of Object (which can be int, double, string or array or any other type).

E.g. the input is as follows:

```
key1, [R1_Entry_1, R1_Entry_2, ..., R1_Entry_n]
key1, [R2_Entry_1, R2_Entry_2, ..., R2_Entry_n]
key1, [R3_Entry_1, R3_Entry_2, ..., R3_Entry_n]
key2, [R4_Entry_1, R4_Entry_2, ..., R4_Entry_n]
... 
keyJ, [RK_Entry_1, RK_Entry_2, ..., RK_Entry_n]
... 
keyX, [RM_Entry_1, RM_Entry_2, ..., RM_Entry_n]
```

Then `RI_entry_J` (row I and entry J) is a java.lang.Object and could be an int, a double, a string, an ArrayList or any other type.

I have used `JavaRDD.reduceByKey()` , to reduce the entry into a new list. My desired output should be (assuming `key1` has only three corresponding rows (the first three rows: R1, R2, R3).)

```
key1, [[R1_Entry_1, R2_Entry_1,R3_Entry_1], [R1_Entry_2, R2_Entry_2,R3_Entry_2], ..., [R1_Entry_n, R2_Entry_n,R3_Entry_n]]
... 
keyJ, [[RK_Entry_1, R*_Entry_1, ...], [RK_Entry_2, R*_Entry_2, ...], ..., [RK_Entry_n, R*_Entry_n, ...]]
...
```

My code is as follows:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, ArrayList> AdjJavaRDD =  JavaRDD.reduceByKey(new Function2<ArrayList, ArrayList, ArrayList>() {
@Override
public ArrayList call(ArrayList v1, ArrayList v2) throws Exception {

    int v1Len = v1.size();
    int v2Len = v2.size();
    if (v1Len != v2Len) {
        System.out.println(" \n The input size is incorrect. Please check! \n  ");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>(v1Len);
    for (int i =0; i < v1Len; i++)
    {
        List<Object> obj_i = new ArrayList<>();
        Object v1i = v1.get(i);
        Object v2i = v2.get(i);
        obj_i.add(v1i);
        obj_i.add(v2i);
        obj.add(i, obj_i);
    }
    return new ArrayList(obj);
}
});
```

and I get results as follows:
`key1, [[[R1_Entry_1, R2_Entry_1],R3_Entry_1], [[R1_Entry_2, R2_Entry_2],R3_Entry_2], ..., [[R1_Entry_n, R2_Entry_n],R3_Entry_n]]`

I.e. the entries are nested inside list instead of writing into a list withnout nesting.

Exmaple if `Entry_1` is integer, and `KeyJ` has five correponding rows with the five `Entry_1` as `1, 2, 3,4, 5`. The result for `KeyJ` using my code is
`KeyJ, [[[[[1,2],3], 4], 5], ...]` (in real calculation, the order of the integer will be random).
Hoever, what I want is
`KeyJ, [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ...]`

Any idea hot to avoid such nested list in the Spark code in Java?

Comment: The above code may dot not work at all, I am trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution. The reason that above code does not work is that `Object v1i = v1.get(i);` will return a particular object, e.g. `v1i` as `String` (or any other data type) when it is first called. However, when it is called afterwards, `v1i` becomes a `ArrayList`, that is why the code in the question return nested list.

The updated solution is as follows:

```
  JavaPairRDD<Tuple2, ArrayList> JavaRDDColumns = adjJavaRDD.reduceByKey(new Function2<ArrayList, ArrayList, ArrayList>() {
            @Override
            public ArrayList call(ArrayList v1, ArrayList v2) throws Exception {
                int v1Len = v1.size();
                int v2Len = v2.size();

                Object[] objArr = new Object[v1Len];
                for (int i = 0; i < v1Len; i++) {
                    ArrayList<Object> obj_i = new ArrayList<Object>();
                    Object obj1i = v1.get(i);
                    Object obj2i = v2.get(i);
                    List<Object> obj1Arr = new ArrayList<>();
                    List<Object> obj2Arr = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (obj1i instanceof List<?>) {
                        obj1Arr = (List) obj1i;
                    } else {
                        obj1Arr = Arrays.asList(obj1i);  // not a Arraylist, convert to a Arraylist
                    }

                    if (obj2i instanceof List<?>) {
                        obj2Arr = (List) obj2i;
                    } else {
                        obj2Arr = Arrays.asList(obj2i);
                    }
                    List<Object> combineList = ListUtils.union(obj1Arr, obj2Arr);
                    objArr[i] = combineList;
                }
                ArrayList<Object> obj = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(objArr));
                return obj;
            }
        });
```